# How can I edit many LastPass preferences at once?

Tags: google-chrome, password-management, lastpass

But to edit my LastPass passwords list, I have to do *way* too many clicks. Especially when it has remembered many passwords for different servers on the same domain, but it just distinguishes them by (2) (3) (4) etc. instead of by server name or URL.

So...is there any way to get like a "table" of my LastPass password that shows me the *full* URL each is associated with, the username, and the password, all in one view, so I can know what the (2) (3) (4) are without clicking through?

Even if I can't edit from such a table that would be great. But if it were also possible to bulk apply settings e.g. autofill, autologin etc., that would also be very helpful. Thanks! PS I'm using LastPass on Google Chrome 6 on Mac OS X--not sure if that matters.

Comment: To any moderator, I've flagged this as perhaps belonging on webapps since it has no answers here after so many months? Not sure which category LastPass falls under; my apologies if this post is misplaced or if I misflagged it....

Comment: the question is on topic - perhaps back then there was no way to get an export.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LastPass Chrome extension comes with an export feature, you can find it under LastPass -> Tools -> Export To. Select "LastPass" CSV.

The first row indicates the order of the columns

```
url,username,password,extra,name,grouping,fav
```

Once you've exported the CSV - you an open it in Excel, edit it to whatever you want & reimport it back into LastPass

Comment: I am 90% sure the Firefox plugin has the import/export feature too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Indeed - I mentioned Chrome Extension specifically since @Philip had mentioned he uses CHrome

Comment: sounds perfect; I'll give it a try and report back! Thanks!

Comment: @Philip you're welcome, do keep us updated